# Is it possible to adjust a second graph to a second y-axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a several bar plots with their standard errors added to the plot. I tried to add a second y-axis, which was not that hard, however, now I also want my standard errors to fit this new y-axis. I know that I can manipulate the y-axis, but this is not really what I want. I want it such that the standard errors fit to this new y-axis. To illustrate, this is the plot I have now, where I just divided the first y-axis by a 100.
[image]

but what I want it something more like this

[How it should look like using Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ5pB.png)

to show for all barplots (this was done for the first barplot using Excel). Here is my code

```
df_bar <- as.data.frame(
rbind(
c('g1', 0.945131015,      1.083188828,                 1.040164338,                 
  1.115716593,                 0.947886795),
c('g2', 1.393211286,      1.264193745,                 1.463434395,                 
  1.298126006,                 1.112718796),
 c('g3', 1.509976099,      1.450923745,                 1.455102201,                 
       1.280102338,                 1.462689245),
     c('g4', 1.591697668,      1.326292649,                 1.767207296,                 
    1.623619341,                 2.528108183),
     c('g5', 2.625114848,      2.164050167,                 2.092843287,                 
   2.301950359,                 2.352736806)
 )
  ) 

       colnames(df_bar)<-c('interval', 'lvl3.Mellem.Høj',    'lvl1.Lav',     'TOM',         
        ',lvl4.Høj',                 'lvl2.Lav.Mellem')



          df_bar <- melt(df_bar, id.vars = "interval",
           variable.name = "name", 
           value.name = "value")


        df_line <- as.data.frame(
        rbind(
        c('g1', 0.0212972,    0.0164494,                0.0188898,                 0.01888982,                 
        0.03035883),
        c('g2', 0.0195600,    0.0163811,                 0.0188747,                0.01887467,                
        0.03548092),
        c('g3', 0.0192249,    0.0161914,               0.02215852,                0.02267605,                 
        0.03426538),
        c('g4', 0.0187961,    0.0180842,               0.01962371,                0.02103450,                 
        0.03902890),
        c('g5', 0.0209987,    0.0164596,               0.01838280,                0.02282300,                 
        0.03516818)
        )
        ) 

        colnames(df_line)<-c('interval', 'lvl3.Mellem.Høj',   'lvl1.Lav',     'TOM',         
         ',lvl4.Høj',                 'lvl2.Lav.Mellem')

         df_line <- melt(df_line, id.vars = "interval",
            variable.name = "name", 
            value.name = "sd")


            df <- inner_join(df_bar,df_line, by=c("interval", "name"))

            df %>%
              mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
              mutate(sd = as.numeric(sd)) %>%
              mutate(interval = as.factor(interval)) %>%
             mutate(name = as.factor(name)) %>%
              ggplot() +
          geom_bar(aes(x = interval, y = value, fill = interval), stat = "identity") + 
              geom_line(aes(x = interval, y = sd, group = 1), 
             color = "black", size = .75) +
             scale_y_continuous("Value", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . /100, name = "sd")) +
           facet_grid(~name, scales = "free") +
             theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "none") +
           xlab("Interval") + ylab("Value") +
             labs(caption = "Black line indicates standard deviation.")
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean? Don't divide the second axis by 100 and it will fit perfectly to the first axis.

Comment: Ye that is an option but I would like to add the second y-axis and then adjust the geom_line accordingly to this new y-axis such that the geom_lines placing does not depend on the values of the first y-axis. Does this make sense? This is possible in Excel. I have attached a picture to show how the first barplot should look like.

Comment: You could do it without data transformation if you just change the labels of the secondary axis to `function(x) x/100`

Comment: @mzuba this still does not fix the issue that the values from `sd` do not match the axis labels. To achieve this @Mathias Nisssen needs to also transform the `sd` values to the matching range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in this [example](https://r-graph-gallery.com/line-chart-dual-Y-axis-ggplot2.html), you have to also perform a transformation to your values from `sd` to match the scale of your second axis. In your example you divided by 100, therefore you have to multiply your `sd` by 100 as shown in the below:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  mutate(sd = as.numeric(sd)) %>%
  mutate(interval = as.factor(interval)) %>%
  mutate(name = as.factor(name)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = interval, y = value, fill = interval), stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous("Value", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./100, name = "sd"))+
  geom_line(aes(x = interval, y = sd*100, group = 1), 
            color = "black", size = .75)+
  facet_grid(~name, scales = "free")+
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "none") +
  xlab("Interval") + ylab("Value") +
  labs(caption = "Black line indicates standard deviation.")
```

[image]

You can also use a different value to scale your second axis. In this example I used 50 as a scaling factor, which in my opinion looks a bit better:

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this works. I guess finding the maximum in df_bar and df_line and then dividing the twos will yield the best outcome in the general case (I have to do this for a lot of graphs and it has to be done automatically every once in a while, so it needs to be dynamic).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what it should look like for the first barplot using Excel.

[image: From Excel]